# In estimating a posterior mean, should one use the entire density or the HPDI?

Tags: bayesian, mean, posterior, reporting, credible-interval

Recognizing that HPDIs are analogous to confidence intervals in frequentist statistics, if one calculates an HPDI for a posterior distribution and then wants to report a posterior mean, does it make sense to estimate the mean based on the density contained within the HPDI or is one to use the entire posterior density to calculate the mean?  Any insight would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Using "the" HPD region would imply selecting a probability level for picking which HPD region is used. I cannot think of a non-artificial loss function that would lead to this posterior trimmed mean being the associate Bayes estimator.

Comment: If you use the mean within the HPDI, it is not the (posterior) mean any more.

Comment: A side remark: if the HPD region is disconnected, i.e., made of several connected sets (intervals), as happens for a multimodal prior, it may well be that the mean over the HPD region does not belong to the HPD region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both HPDI and mean are summaries of the posterior distribution. Why would you want to calculate mean inside of the interval? To give simple counterexample, say that you are interested in the 5% quantile not the mean and have 50% HPDI, it’d be useless for calculating the quantile. It’s less useless for mean, but still you would be calculating mean based on partial information. There are cases where you would like to use statistics like [windsorized mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsorized_mean), but if you assume that your probabilistic model gets the tails of the distribution so wrong that you need to discard them, than maybe you should choose better model instead of hacking the results?

Comment: Thanks @Tim.  This is what I was looking for and your explanation really helped to drive home how to think about the posterior mean and other summaries of the posterior distribution.